# Is IIS 8.5 Express available for developer workstations?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are moving to Windows 2012 R2 servers from Windows 2008 R2 and I am wondering if there is an IIS 8.5 Express version which can be installed on developer workstations (They are mostly Windows 7 at this point).  In web Platform installer I only see IIS 8.0 Express and have not found a definitive answer if an IIS 8.5 express is available.

Comment: IIS 8 should be fine, is there any specific functionality in 8.5 you're looking for?

Comment: Nope, more of just making sure I have the latest bits and to avoid potential issues between dev and other environments.

Comment: I wouldn't worry, according to this page ( http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85 ) there isn't any functionality that changes the developer experience. HTTP/2 is exclusive to Windows 10 (and Server 2016, not Server 2012 R2), so I'd stick with 8.